# Are there German paraprosdokians?

Tags: sentence-structure, prefix, joke

A paraprosdokian is a sentence that starts out leading the reader/listener to think it is heading one direction, but then it has a surprise ending. For instance, Groucho Marx, "I've had a wonderful evening, but this wasn't it."

It seems to me that German may be perfectly setup for this because of the device of detaching prefixes from verbs and sending them to the end of a sentence. I have often wondered if Germans, when hearing a very long sentence, guess at the prefix that is to come from context -- and if so, they'd be setting themselves up to be surprised when a prefix arrives that is different from the guess.

So my question is -- are there such playful sentences in German?

Comment: VTC,since the answer is simply: Yes.

Comment: I would love to learn an example...

Comment: Do you think that other languages - like English (as you write in English) does not allow that? Or do you think that German is/might be prone to be used by paraprosdokians and look for hints/examples/proves?

Comment: Every first half of a sentence continued with a "but" or its companions contradict the meaning of the first half. I will help you but... / The direction is to the left but...

Comment: (A question to whoever decides to do such things) What's the point of closing the question??? If it's not good, it doesn't get answers. If it gets answers, and the answers even get upvotes, it's good.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm The second paragraph explains in no uncertain terms what OP is asking about and why German might be special if it comes to such sentences.

Comment: The question is about German #sentence-structure in combination with #prefixed verbs and resulting confusion like it is used in #jokes. It's clearly about German language and doesn't need to be more focused since it is already very clear. It's a good question imo and i vote to reopen.

Comment: @Barry "Ich hätte einen wunderbaren Morgen gehabt, es war aber nicht" <- es ist wahrscheinlich nicht perfekt, aber Muttersprächler würden es verstehen.

Comment: @Barry: I accidently found "Garden-path sentence" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence .  Does that also comes into your mind of "playful sentence"? Reading it for a second longer, an ambiguity might be something else then an unexpected turn...

Answer (score 5):

Needless to say, that you can form phrases like your Groucho Marx example in German.

- Nach dem Referat fragt Marie den Lehrer, wie er ihre Präsentation fand. Der Lehrer: "Das habe ich schon besser gesehen. Allerdings nicht von dir."
- Ein Mann mit Geigenkasten fragt einen Passanten: "Wie komme ich zur Staatsoper?"
  Passant: "Üben, üben, üben!"

I guess you will get a lot of examples in the community Wiki.

But I think, that's not really **the most interesting part of your question**.

Since you are specifically asking for a twist taking advantage of verbal affixes, there are three conditions to form such a surprising sentence.

1. You need a Situation that points in one direction. Since the verb is taking the part of the twist builder, the subject should place the whole situation into a specific picture.
2. The affixed verb needs to fit the subject in the expected situation.
3. there must be a different affix for the same verb that also fits the subject but not the expected situation.

> Der Richter lud 10 Zeugen ein.
>
> Alle Zeugen sagten bereitwillig ein Gedicht auf.

The subject *Richter* (judge) places the situation into a court room. A typical action of a judge is *vorladen* (to summon). The object *Zeugen* (witnesses) supports the visualized picture of the situation. Then the twist - instead of *vorladen* we get *einladen* (invite).

*Zeugen* usually testify (aussagen). Here they recite a poem (aufsagen).

---

Things like that usually don't happen in common communication. There is always a context and usually the verb fits the subject in that context. So

> I have often wondered if Germans, when hearing a very long sentence, guess at the prefix that is to come from context

Germans don't really need to guess, they are anticipating of course. But:

> and if so, they'd be setting themselves up to be surprised when a prefix arrives that is different from the guess.

No, they don't. They expect one or the other possible outcome if there are several. And that actually is the informative substance of the message.

Answer (score 5):

Comedian Heinz Erhardt used such sentences in his shows. Examples:

> Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen.
>
> Lasst uns den Abend genießen, Genossen. Halt, das stimmt nicht: *genießen*, Komma, *genossen* wir doch selten einen so schönen.

The second sentence plays with the fact that *Genossen* (=comrades, a term used in socialist and communist parties for members of the same party) is the same as the preterite plural of *genießen* (to enjoy), only the capitalization is different.

But I wouldn't say that such sentences are more frequent in German than in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with grammar, but one type of German surprise ending joke are ones starting *Alle Kinder ...* . They're a bit like knock-knock jokes only very dark. One example is *Alle Kinder schauen auf den großen Felsen, nur nicht Gunter, der liegt drunter.* Roughly translated, it's "All the children are looking at the large boulder, except Gunter, who's under it." Google "alle kinder witze" for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sentences that lead the audience in a wrong direction are either stylistically bad, or humouristic.

I am, however, not sure how clearly you want to limit this to the boundaries of one single sentence. If you accept misleading beginnings and surprising ends in longer pieces of text, then actually an entire genre of the dramatic arts is built upon this, namely comedy.

The Greek *para prosdokia* means simply: against expectation.

Here are some examples for humouristic sentences with surprising endings.

(*Note: This is a community Wiki. Everybody can add more examples.*)

- Erstens kommt es anders, zweitens als man denkt.
- Geld allein macht nicht glücklich; aber es beruhigt ungemein.
- "Grüß Gott!" - "Gern, wenn ich ihn sehe."
- Another famous example is the poem [Dunkel war’s, der Mond schien helle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkel_war%E2%80%99s,_der_Mond_schien_helle). See also [here](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Dunkel_war%E2%80%99s,_der_Mond_schien_helle).